# Disable text layer syntax checking in Dymola

Tags: dymola

When working in the text layer of a model, I often reference existing models to see how the thing I'm trying to do was implemented. For example, if I'm in the middle of editing "Unnamed1" below and want to switch to "Unnamed2" to check something, Dymola pops up an error dialog box because of a missing semicolon in "Unnamed1". I have to choose the option "Correct error later" before being able to switch to "Unnamed2". And then once I go back to "Unnamed1", I need to click "Cancel Switch" on another dialog box that pops up before I can edit "Unnamed1" again.
[image: Model Switching Error]

I'd like to disable this syntax checking feature so that I can freely switch between models, akin to how Matlab or Python works where a script file can contain errors and will only generate warnings/errors when trying to run the script. Is there a setting that can be changed to do this?

For reference, I'm using 2021x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second warning is removed in Dymola 2023x Refresh 1.

However, there is not yet the possibility to completely avoid the first warning.

The reason is that if there are syntax errors the graphical user interface will not work reliably when *using* the model (drag'n'drop, connect, set parameters, etc) and the model cannot be *modified* graphically (as the text layer contain everything including the graphics).